# Custom hitbox detection in Spigot 1.8.8

Tags: bukkit

Hi I wanted to create a custom hitbox system in Spigot 1.8.8. This is my code but for some reason the list is empty. I want to use this because I want to use it in a plugin I am creating.

```
public static List<LivingEntity> getLivingEntities(Player caster, Dimension dimension) {
    //Input
    List<LivingEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Vector direction = caster.getLocation().getDirection();
    
    double x = dimension.getX();
    double y = dimension.getY();
    int frequency = (int) dimension.getZ();
    
    //Calculation
    for(int i = frequency; i > 0; i--) {
        Collection<Entity> entities = caster.getWorld().getNearbyEntities(caster.getLocation().add(direction.multiply((x/frequency) * i)), y, y, y);
        for(Entity e: entities) {
            if(e instanceof LivingEntity) {
                LivingEntity le = (LivingEntity) e;
                if(!list.contains(le)) {
                    list.add(le);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Output
    return list;
}
```

This is my Dimensions class

```
public class Dimension {

private double x;
private double y;
private double z;

public Dimension(double x, double y, double z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public double getZ() {
    return z;
}

public void setZ(double z) {
    this.z = z;
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the `frequency` variable equal to at runtime? If `Dimension`'s z-value is zero, it wouldn't iterate the for loop at all. This could also be true for having no nearby entities?